# Rotate cube on button click in Unity3D

Tags: button, unity-game-engine, rotation, unityscript

I have created one cube. I want to rotate that cube on button click.
I created script for rotating cube and another script for button click.
Now how can I make that cube rotate on this button click.

**Code for Button:**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
public class ButtonInput1 : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame


    Button button=null;
    void Rotate()
    {
        a++;
    button.onClick.AddListener (delegate() {    PlayerController.CubeRotate ();});

    }
}
```

**Code for RotateCube:**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    // Update is called once per frame
    int a=1;
    public  void CubeRotate () {
    if (Input.GetButton("Button1")) {
        a++;
            //transform.Rotate ( new Vector3(15,30,45) * Time.deltaTime);
    }
        if (a % 2 == 0) {
            transform.Rotate ( new Vector3(15,30,45) * Time.deltaTime);

        }
    }

}
```

I just need to know, how to call cube's script on this button click. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rotate object continuously on button click Unity3D](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31063088/rotate-object-continuously-on-button-click-unity3d)

Answer (score 0):

Thats funny, i actually just answered this question worded exactly like yours asked by another person. [Rotate object continuously on button click Unity3D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31063088/rotate-object-continuously-on-button-click-unity3d/31063246#31063246)