# Rotate object continuously on button click Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I have a `button` and a `PlayerObject`. When I click the button, the object must rotate continuously, and when I click the same button again, the object must stop rotating. Currently, I am using the code given below. It makes the object only rotate once to a certain angle.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {
    int a=1;
    public  void CubeRotate () {
        a++;
        transform.Rotate (new Vector3 (150, 300, 60) * Time.deltaTime);

        if (a%2==0) {
                    Debug.Log(a);
                        transform.Rotate (new Vector3 (150, 300, 60) * Time.deltaTime);

            }
    }
}
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a very simple toggle. The reason your rotation is so clunky though is because it only runs the rotate command when `CubeRotate()` is called, thus not rotating *continuously* like you planned. Instead move the rotation command out into an `Update()` method, which runs on every frame.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {

    protected bool rotate = false;

    public void CubeRotate () {
        rotate = !rotate;
    }

    public void Update() {
        if(rotate)
        {
            transform.Rotate (new Vector3 (150, 300, 60) * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
}
```